# cannot convert from object to string in C#

Tags: c#, dataset, datarow

I am not sure how to deal with this error I am getting:
"cannot convert from object to string"

```
row["timeinseconds"] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( double.Parse( r["timeinseconds"] ) ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

The timeinseconds is coming from a sqlite database and its stored as an integer value

I need to parse it as a double so I can use the from seconds method of timespan so I can convert it to the right format

```
private void updateDgvTimesheet()
{
    dgvTimesheet.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow r in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DataRow row = this.dataset.Tables[0].NewRow();

        row["taskname"] = r["taskname"];

        row["timeinseconds"] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( double.Parse( r["timeinseconds"] ) ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        row["date"] = r["date"];
        row["paid"] = r["paid"];

        dgvTimesheet.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `r["timeinseconds"]` in `double.Parse( r["timeinseconds"] )` ?

Comment: Try formatting to string first `double.Parse(r["timeinseconds"].ToString())`, or maybe `(double)((int)r["timeinseconds"])` if you are sure it's an `int`.

Comment: Yup, if it's a cell from a DataTable, you'll have to `.TosTring()` it to get its value, otherwise it's just an object.

Comment: If you have an `int` and want a `double`, why go through a `string` as an intermediary?  Seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: @juharr, correct that's the solution.

Comment: @ElwinArens The datatype is integer

Comment: Your `.ToString()` is being called on the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` and you likely only want to call it on the `r["timeinseconds"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `r["timeinseconds"].ToString()`

Change your function to be:

```
private void updateDgvTimesheet()
{
    dgvTimesheet.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow r in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DataRow row = this.dataset.Tables[0].NewRow();

        row["taskname"] = r["taskname"];

        row["timeinseconds"] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( double.Parse( r["timeinseconds"].ToString() ) ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        row["date"] = r["date"];
        row["paid"] = r["paid"];

        dgvTimesheet.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```